# multiple if checks in ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement, ng-class

So I have this piece of code in my angularjs app that I include in a table. I want to activate the class 'rare' if the index is 0, 1 or 2 only. The index is the rows. Let's say I have 8 rows in my table. Only the first 3 in it should have the class 'rare' applied to it.

`ng-class="{rare : $index === 0,  rare : $index === 1, rare : $index === 2}"`

But is there an easier/shorter way of writing it?
Is this good practice? I dont think it looks very good, even though it works.
How would you write the if checks?

I tried:

`ng-class="{rare : $index === {0,1,2}}` but it didn't work

Comment: Hey @rick astley - check out my answer - even though you have accepted another answer - mine is a very simply one line solution for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this, if you have an list of values.

```js
var app = angular.module("sampleApp", []);

app.controller("sampleController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.data = "Test";
    $scope.rareList = [1, 2, 3];
    $scope.val1 = 2;
    $scope.val2 = 5;
  }
]);
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
.not-active {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="sampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="sampleController">
    <div ng-class="rareList.includes(val1)? 'active' : 'not-active'">{{data}}</div>
    <div ng-class="rareList.includes(val2)? 'active' : 'not-active'">{{data}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The thing is, I want to write it on 1 line. My code works but i just want to shorten it down. if I use your code, I'd still have to make 3 checks. I just wonder if there is any way to make it check if index is 0, 1 or 2 a bit nicer. I there perhaps a way to pass in an array of values in "includes"? If so, then your code would be amazing

Comment: Ohhhh...... now I understand your code. So I'd write: `[1,2,3].includes(index) ? 'rare' : ''` right?

Comment: Yes.. just check for the value index. and assign

Comment: You could also have the list in the controller and have the same check, updated the snippet as well

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something here - if $index is the row index - it must always start at 0 and then increment. Therefore you can ignore the lower limit and simply test if the index is less than the upper limit (note that $index will be zero indexed (unless you explicitly set it to start at 1) so therefore testing if $index is less than three will allow you to select row index 0, 1 and 2).

```
ng-class="{rare: $index < 3}"
```

```js
var app = angular.module("sampleApp", []);

    app.controller("sampleController", ["$scope",
      function($scope) {
        $scope.data = ['test1','test2','test3','test4'];
      }
    ]);
```

```css
.rare {
    color: red;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-app="sampleApp">
      <div ng-controller="sampleController">
        <div ng-class="{rare: $index < 3}" ng-repeat="datum in data">{{datum}} ($index = {{$index}})</div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
ng-class="{rare : [0,1,2].indexOf($index) >= 0}}
```